# When to return 'this' instead of 'void' in a method and why?

Tags: c#, oop, method-chaining, fluent-interface

What are the benefits (or drawbacks) of returning a reference to 'this' object in a method that modifies itself? When should returning a 'this' be used as apposed to void?

When looking at an [answer on code review stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/150861/210654), I noticed that the answer used a 'return this' in a self operating method.

Simplified class from original:

```
class Item
{
    public Item(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Item AddComponent(ItemComponent component)
    {
        _components.Add(component);
        return this;
    }

    private List<ItemComponent> _components = new List<ItemComponent>();
}
```

Consuming code simplified:

```
var fireSword = new Item("Lightbringer")
                   .AddComponent(new Valuable { Cost = 1000 })
                   .AddComponent(new PhysicalDamage { Slashing = 10 });
```

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57140/is-there-any-disadvantage-to-returning-this-instead-of-void) seems to have conflicting answers by different users.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417276/what-is-the-difference-between-void-method-and-return-this) is also similar with the answer referencing fluent interfaces to use in object creation.

Comment: Because you can then chain method calls. Only for convenience... in the example there would be another solution, e.g. an `AddMany` method which takes a container or so.

Comment: This pattern is often called a `fluent` api.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Returning `this` is using a [**fluent interface**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) design, that is a special case of [**method chaining**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) when the return type is of the current object on which we are applying the method.

Method chaining is also the root of [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FP_(programming_language)).

It is extensively used by **Linq** extension methods with `IEnumerable<>` and `IQueryable<>`.

It allows to call methods on the same object in a chained manner without repeating a variable name for each method call.

Therefore, this produces a shorter, cleaner and more maintainable code with fewer sources of errors.

So we use this when we want or need that.